# netcat missing -x option

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, netcat

I am having problem with nc command, I cannot use a proxy, because there is no -x option, which should be there.

```
 nc -h
[v1.10-41]
connect to somewhere:   nc [-options] hostname port[s] [ports] ...
listen for inbound:     nc -l -p port [-options] [hostname] [port]
options:
        -c shell commands       as `-e'; use /bin/sh to exec [dangerous!!]
        -e filename             program to exec after connect [dangerous!!]
        -b                      allow broadcasts
        -g gateway              source-routing hop point[s], up to 8
        -G num                  source-routing pointer: 4, 8, 12, ...
        -h                      this cruft
        -i secs                 delay interval for lines sent, ports scanned
        -k                      set keepalive option on socket
        -l                      listen mode, for inbound connects
        -n                      numeric-only IP addresses, no DNS
        -o file                 hex dump of traffic
        -p port                 local port number
        -r                      randomize local and remote ports
        -q secs                 quit after EOF on stdin and delay of secs
        -s addr                 local source address
        -T tos                  set Type Of Service
        -t                      answer TELNET negotiation
        -u                      UDP mode
        -v                      verbose [use twice to be more verbose]
        -w secs                 timeout for connects and final net reads
        -C                      Send CRLF as line-ending
        -z                      zero-I/O mode [used for scanning]
port numbers can be individual or ranges: lo-hi [inclusive];
hyphens in port names must be backslash escaped (e.g. 'ftp\-data').
```

Is my netcat outdated? How do I update it? Thanks for help.

Comment: If you are going to (re)install something, I suggest you also look at [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/). It provides even more combinations of options.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like you have [the "traditional" netcat](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/nc.traditional.1.html) (`netcat-traditional`) installed. The `-x` option is available in [the OpenBSD netcat](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/nc_openbsd.1.html) (`netcat-openbsd`). See also: [What are the differences between netcat-traditional and netcat-openbsd?](https://askubuntu.com/q/346869/158442) on Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 5):

There are multiple implementations of netcat, you probably want the BSD one, because it provides the `-x` option. In Ubuntu it is available in the `netcat-openbsd` package.